# Microsoft word: Copying text from multiple text boxes into a select table

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to copy only bold text from multiple text boxes in a word document and paste it into a selected column in a table in different rows. For example the bold text from textbox 1 should go into row 2 and column 2 of the table. Similarly, text from textbox 2 should go into row 3 and column 2 of the table. This should continue till all textboxes have been read and copied.

However the code I am trying is copying all text from all text boxes and pasting it into different rows . I have not been able to figure out how to extract only bold text from the textbox and paste text from messagebox 1 into row 1, message box 2 into row 2 and so on.

I am new to VBA so any help will be highly appreciated.

The code I have customized is as follows:

```
Sub Copytextfromtextbox()
    Dim nNumber As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    Dim i As Long
    With ActiveDocument
For nNumber = 1 To .Shapes.Count Step 1
If .Shapes(nNumber).Type = msoTextBox Then
       strText = strText & .Shapes(nNumber).TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCr
  For i = 2 To nNumber Step 1
         With ActiveDocument.Tables(5).Cell(Row:=i, Column:=2).Range
     .Delete
     .InsertAfter Text:=strText
 End With
 Next
    Else
MsgBox ("There is no textbox.")
    End If
  Next
End With
        End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Code mostly worked except (i) if there is no bold text in the textbox, the code copies the entire text contained in the text box; (ii) the part of the code MsgBox ("There is no texbox") is not executing as no message is displayed if there is not textbox in the document. I am trying but have not been successful yet. Any suggestions will ber very helpful. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly what you need is not clear, it would help to give an example of what the content of a text box could be and what part should be transferred to a table cell. The following will do what I understand to be the requirement:

> Loop all Shapes in a document. If the Shape is a TextBox, locate the
>   bold text and transfer it to the second column of a specific table, in
>   the row index +1 of the position of the text box in the document
>   (first in row 2, second in row 3, and so on).

Note that I've added *object variables* for the Word "things" the code uses, such as a `Document`, a `Table`, a `Range` and a `Shape`. This is more efficient, easier to follow and less prone to working with the wrong thing.

Looping the Shapes is clearer using `For Each`.

In order to pick up the **bold** text, Word's `Find` functionality is efficient. This is performed on the `TextRange` of the textbox. (For more information about using `Find` please refer to the Word VBA language reference and the many contributions that use it here and elsewhere on the Internet. Working with Word's "Advanced Find" in the Word application, as a user, and recording a macro is also instructive.)

Every time a text box is found, `i` is incremented in order to identify the table row.

```
Sub Copytextfromtextbox()
    Dim nNumber As Integer
    Dim strText As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set tbl = doc.Tables(5)
    i = 0
    With doc
        For Each shp In .Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoTextBox Then
                Set rng = shp.TextFrame.TextRange
                With rng.Find
                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindStop
                    .Execute
                    strText = rng.Text
                End With
                i = i + 1
                With tbl.Cell(Row:=i + 1, Column:=2).Range
                    .Delete
                    .InsertAfter Text:=strText
                End With
            Else
                MsgBox ("There is no textbox.")
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: One more question please. The above code is not copying from the first text box to the last textbox in the table. It is copying the text from the textbox that was inserted first in the document to the next and so on. For example, if textbox 2 was inserted above textbox 1 in the document then the text from textbox 2 will be copied first in the table. Kindly advise, how I can reset the sequence of all textboxes so that the text is always copied from the first textbox to the last. Thank you

Comment: @Quantmodels The reasoning for this subsequent issue is somewhat complex. Handling it here would detract from the core stated question: how to move each text box's content to a specific table row/cell. Would you mind asking this in a new question, specifically stating this problem, please? Stack Overflow's goal is to be a Q&A to help everyone, so it's important that questions and answers are narrowly targeted, making information easier to find and understand. If we get the second part sorted satisfactorily, we can link to that as a "next step"...

Comment: Sure thanks so much for your help. I posted it as a separate question.